# PHP: Getting duplicate inserts when utilizing SQLite

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

At the beginning of my script I delete everything in the table. When running the code below it is iterating 3 times (one for each record) however when I check the data after the fact the information is being duplicated (6 inserts instead of 3).

```
  foreach ($response2->records as $record) {    

    $accountid = $record->fields->AccountId;
    $resident_title = $record->fields->Resident_Title__c;
    $supervisor_title = $record->fields->Supervisor_Title__c;
    $position_proposal_url = $record->fields->Position_Proposal_URL__c;  

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Positions (AccountID, Position_Title, Supervisor_Title, Position_Url) 
    VALUES ('$accountid',
    '$resident_title',
    '$supervisor_title',
    '$position_proposal_url');";

    $result2 = $database->exec($sql);
  }
```

I have inserted a print command prior to the last line to determine the content of the SQL and to visualize that it is in fact only looping through 3 times. So based on that I suspect the problem must be with my PHP/SQL syntax.

Comment: Have you tried a `print_r($response2);` (instead of the foreach) to see if there are, in fact, 3 records or 6?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a CSS or inline style that has an empty background url?

Fire up your page using Firefox/Firebug or something similar that will allow you to trap all http traffic - it is most likely your page is being hit twice.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting area to explore. What area within Firebug should I be utilizing and what types of things should I look for?

Comment: @joseph - Once you have Firebug up, jump to the Net tab. Click "Persist", then "Clear", then load your page. You are checking for where the page itself is being retrieved twice by hovering over all POST/GET commands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your database shouldn't be allowing duplicate rows. Fix that problem, and attempts to insert duplicate keys should cause an error you can follow.